# Update style of element based on other elements focus

Tags: html, css

I have a requirement where I need to set special style to an element of its children is focused. Issue is, the changes are not reflected if the element is not self of children of element in action.

In the below example, I'm using a variable `--bg-color` as background for *Test1*, *Test3* and *Test4*.

This variable is update on hover for:

- *Test2* to Blue
- *Test3* to Black

If you notice,

- *Test1* never has an update
- *Test3* changes background on *Test2*'s hover but not on Test4's hover

```css
:root {
  --bg-color: lightblue;
}

div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.test1 {
  background: var(--bg-color)
}
.test2{
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.test3, .test4 {
  background: var(--bg-color);
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.test2:hover {
  --bg-color: blue;
}

.test3:hover {
  --bg-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">Test 1</div>
<div class="test2">
  Test 2
  <div class="test3">Test 3</div>
  
  <div class="test4">Test 4</div>
</div>
```

So the question is, can we do this in anyway just by using CSS and is there a restriction for repaint?

**Note:** I'm aware I can use JS to add class to an element and update style based on it but CSS is faster and my usecase needs css approach. This is just a sample of problem

Comment: I'm still not sure to understand well the issue but you cannot modify a container style based on child focus. al least not in a simple way with CSS

Comment: Focus-within might be what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I guess you know that the various --bg-color have scopes? Changing it for test3 does not change the setting for :root, only for test3 (and any descendants possibly).

Comment: @AHaworth I did not know this until yesterday. I assumed, once declared, it'll be used across but later realised it will not override but will create new copies and give it preference. Will remove the post later